# ImageView set as default in Android

Tags: android, imageview

I was searching on the web for setting the `imageView` to a default size, whether the `imageView` changes when I click a button. So far I have tried this two.

```
android:scaleType="fitXY"
android:adjustViewBounds="true"
```

Still my `ImageView` expands when I click a button to change the image it contains.
Is there a way to set the `ImageView` size default whether it changes it`s content on a button click event?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes simple use:

```
<ImageView
    android:src="@drawable/somebackground"
    android:layout_width="40dp"
    android:layout_height="40dp"/>
```

Instead of `wrap_content` or `match_parent`.

**Edit**:

If the image size you change to is different then remember to use some kind of `scaleType` (I prefer `android:scaleType="centerCrop"`).